# D Flip Flops using logic gates

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I am trying to create this D Flip Flop using only logic gates:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uShzJ.jpg]

So far I have this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9wz1.png]

Am I missing anything here? There should only be one input of c and an output of B1, so would this be correct or is the inverter in the wrong place?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the two "LD" symbols are for level-sensitive latches rather than edge-triggered flip-flops, and that you are trying to combine the two latches to make a flip-flop. If that's the case then the only thing you are missing is that the C input needs to be inverted for the first latch. You need to add one inverter between the C input and the G input of the first latch, but the C input connects directly (not inverted) to the second latch. Adding this inverter will make your two latches into a rising-edge-triggered flip-flop and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you!  Would this be correct?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/WzlTK.png

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to describe. The image you linked shows how two latches can be combined to make a flip-flop. Now, to finish the circuit shown at the top of your question you just need to add the inverter from Q back to D.

Comment: Oh so there should be two inverters?  So I just need to add back the inverter I had from my original design?

Comment: To create the circuit shown at the top of the question you need two level-sensitive latches and two inverters. One inverter is used to form the latches into an edge-triggered flip-flop and the second inverter provides the feedback from Q to D in your original circuit.

Comment: Thank you, so this final schematic should be correct?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/l12Es.png

Comment: I think you've got it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The first circuit is a one stage divide by two (binary counter). Normally you don't use an inverter as there is the NOT Q output available. Output 1 0 1 0 and so on.

The second circuit is a two stage Johnson ring and acts as a shift register - output sequence 00 - 10 - 11 - 01 then repeat.

**One stage binary divider circuit. (Master-Slave D type)**

[image]